# Was the radio announcement an innuendo that Vincent would be at Butch's apartment?

Tags: analysis, pulp-fiction

We know what was being played in the background on a radio when Butch comes back to his apartment for the gold watch in *Pulp Fiction*:

[image]

What my question here is: **Was this an indirect clue for us, that Vincent might be there? As Jackrabbit Slim's could only be connected to Vincent and Mia and loosely to Wallace**.Could anyone help me please with any references (interviews /reviews/Making of) where its mentioned that this was intended for us audience?

Answer (score 10):

I cannot find anything confirming that this advert was placed here to foreshadow Vincent's death.

### **However**

An advert for Jack Rabbit Slims also appears in *Reservoir Dogs* when Mr Orange shoots Mr Blonde.

This could just be a case of Tarantino linking his films through this advert.

But as Mr Blonde's real name is Vic Vega, brother of Vincent Vega, there could indeed be foreshadowing here, as both brothers are shot following an advert for Jack Rabbit Slims being played. It could also  just a link between the two films and the brothers and not left deliberately as a clue.

Tarantino just hasn't confirmed a reason why this advert is played in that scene (that I can find).

Comment: Yeah...Tarantino loves to link his movies through his made up product names such as "Red apple cigarettes" which are featured in Pulp Fiction, Kill Bill Vol 1, From Dusk till dawn, four rooms, Planet terror and Inglorious Basterds.  They were also in Romy and Michelle's High school reunion because he was dating Mira Sorvino at the time. 'Big kahuna burger" is another one that he likes to use which was also used in Pulp Fiction, From dusk till dawn, Death Proof, Four rooms and Reservoir Dogs.